# Formula for d(n!)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there any formula for computing the number of divisors of a factorial *d(n!)* ? I know of one in which you obtain the prime factorization.

*n = p^a*, for integer *n*, where *p* is a prime factor, then *d(n) = d(p^a) = a+1*

is there any other explicit formula, in particular for that of a factorial?

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A027423

Comment: In general, the number of divisors of $n = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \dots p_n^{e_n}$ is $(e_1 - 1)(e_2 - 1)\dots(e_n - 1)$

Comment: @MichaelT they should be $+$'es, not $-$'es.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is. Instead of giving it to you straight up, let me derive it for you.

To find the number of divisors of a number $n$, you need to know its prime factorization. In general, if $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ then $d(n)=(\alpha_1+1)\cdots(\alpha_n + 1)$. (Why?) Assume for a moment that we know the prime factorization of $n!$. Specifically, let $v_p(n!)$ denote the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization for $n!$. Then
$$
d(n!)=\prod_{p\text{ prime}\atop p\leq n}(v_p(n!)+1).
$$

It turns out that there is a formula for the number $v_p(n!)$. I'll give the formula, since I knew it already; if you want, I can explain where it comes from.
$$
v_p(n!) = \Big\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\Big\rfloor + 
\Big\lfloor\frac{n}{p^2}\Big\rfloor + \cdots
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\Big\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\Big\rfloor.
$$
Here $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor function, which returns the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. The sum is not actually infinite since the terms become zero as soon as $p^k>n$.

Putting the two together, the formula you want is
$$
d(n!)=\prod_{p\text{ prime}\atop p\leq n}\bigg(1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\Big\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\Big\rfloor\bigg).
$$